# How to find/remove last text portion of innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a `<div>` element that contains both html elements and text. I want to find/remove the last or the last nth or the nth text only portion of it.

So for example

```js
<div id="foo">
   <span id="bar">abcdefg</span>
   <span id="baz">z</span>
</div>
```

If I had a method to delete the last text character, the first call would delete `z` and the second call would delete `g`. Or if I had a method to find the 4th character, it would return `d`.

Comment: Don't work with `innerHTML` if you're trying to change the node tree. Use the normal DOM node functions. That said: the code you're showing has no "both html elements and text", it's an element (div), containing purely elements (span)m, and two elements (span) containing purely text. So you probably need to rewrite your post a little to be more focussed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you only care about the text nodes, so probably something like this so you can just delete the `nth` character:

```js
var div = document.getElementById("foo");

const getTextNodes = (el, nodes) => {
    nodes = nodes || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var curNode = el.childNodes[i];
        if (curNode.nodeName === "#text") {
            if (curNode.textContent.trim().length) {
                nodes.push(curNode);
            }
        } else {
            getTextNodes(curNode, nodes);
        }
    }
    
    return nodes;
}

console.log(getTextNodes(div).map((el) => el.textContent));

const deleteNthCharacter = (el, n) => {
    n--; // since we want to be "1 indexed"
    const nodes = getTextNodes(el);
    let len = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        const curNode = nodes[i];
        if (len + curNode.textContent.length > n) {
            curNode.textContent = curNode.textContent.substring(0, n - len) + curNode.textContent.substring(n + 1 - len);
            break;
        } else {
            len += curNode.textContent.length;
        }
    }
}

deleteNthCharacter(div, 2);
deleteNthCharacter(div, 7);
```

```html
<div id="foo">
   <span id="bar">abcdefg</span>
   <span id="baz">z</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly this should do the trick:

```js
function deleteLastChar(targetId){
    const target = document.getElementById(targetId);
  
  let lastWithText = -1;
  //find last child that has text set
  target.childNodes.forEach((child, iter) => {
    if(child.innerText != undefined && child.innerText.length > 0){
        lastWithText = iter;
    }
  });
  
  // exit if no valid text node was found
  if(lastWithText === -1)
    return;
    
   const lastNode = target.childNodes[lastWithText];
   lastNode.innerText = lastNode.innerText.slice(0, -1);
}

deleteLastChar("foo")
deleteLastChar("foo")
deleteLastChar("foo")
deleteLastChar("foo")
```

```html
<div id="foo">
   <span id="bar">abcdefg</span>
   <span id="baz">z</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question this is probably what you're looking for

```js
let x = document.getElementById('foo').children;
function erase() {
  for (let i = x.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
    if(x[i].textContent.length > 0) {
      const textC = x[i].textContent;
      x[i].textContent = textC.substring(0, textC.length - 1);
      return;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">
   <span id="bar">abcdefg</span>
   <span id="baz">z</span>
</div>
<button onclick="erase()">Erase</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="foo">
   <span id="bar">abcdefg</span><br>
   <span id="baz">z</span><br><br>
   <div id="result"></div>
   <div id="result2"></div>
   
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var s = function(x){
return document.querySelector(x)
}

log = console.log;

var span1 = s("#bar")
var span2 = s("#baz")
var result = s("#result")
var result2 = s("#result2")

var res = span1.innerText.charAt(4)

// with the charAt method
result.innerText = " Result is : " +res+"\n\n"

// with regular Expression

var reg = /e/
result2.innerText = " Result2 is : " +span1.innerText.match(reg)


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but the intention isn't to use known elements. If it is a static layout there would be an easy solution.